# Create a colour palette for tm_fill

Tags: r, colors, palette, choropleth, tmap

I am attempting to create a colour palette which I can use within the tm_fill function in order to be able to create a choropleth map.

```
tm_shape(LdnCensusMap) + tm_borders(col = 'Grey', alpha = 0.3) + tm_fill(col = "Privaterent", palette = sequential_hcl(8, alpha=0.6), title = "Privately Rented (%)", style = "equal", n = 8,) + tm_shape(ldn) +
```

At the moment I am currently using a preset colour palette but I was wondering if there was a way to create your own custom one which I coudld then replace `palette = sequential_hcl(8, alpha=0.6)` with.

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the package `tmaps`, right? You can create palettes with `RColorBrewer`, as they did in this example (which is in the documentation of the package):

```
data(World, Europe, NLD_muni, NLD_prov, land, metro)

if (require(RColorBrewer)) {
pal <- brewer.pal(10, "Set3")[c(10, 8, 4, 5)]
tm_shape(Europe) +
tm_polygons("EU_Schengen", palette=pal, title = "European Countries", 
showNA=FALSE) +
tm_format_Europe()
}
```

You can also choose your colors in HEX format and set a palette like this:

```
# Random colors in HEX. 
Mypal <- c('#313695','#fee090','#d73027','#72001a')

# Ploting the ma again with my custom palette
tm_shape(Europe) +
tm_polygons("EU_Schengen", palette=Mypal, title = "European Countries", 
showNA=FALSE) +
tm_format_Europe()
```